# Django Rest Framework - Create foreign key object on POST

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, foreign-keys

I have a simple DRF REST API that I want to use to create blog articles. I want to be able to add tags to those blog articles so users can search tags and see related articles. However, the tags may not exist yet. I have created an `Article` Model with a ForeignKey field to a `Tag` Model like this:

```
class Tag(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)

    def _str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)

class Article(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    tags = models.ForeignKey(Tag, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, default=None)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('date', 'id')
```

Ideally what I want is to be able to POST a new `Article` with a set of tags, and if any of the tags don't exist, create them in the DB. However, as it is currently, the tags need to already exist to be added to the `Article`. Visually, DRF shows this as a dropdown that is populated with pre-existing tags:

[image: DRF Interface]

How can I add or create multiple `Tag`s from my `Article` API endpoint?

EDIT: As requested, I've added my views.py

views.py:

```
from api.blog.serializers import ArticleSerializer, TagSerializer
from rest_framework import viewsets

# /api/blog/articles
class ArticleView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = Article.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ArticleSerializer

# /api/blog/tags
class TagView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = Tag.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TagSerializer
```

For completeness, here are my serializers from my REST API's serializers.py.

serializers.py:

```
class ArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = '__all__'


class TagSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Tag
        fields = '__all__'
```

urls.py:

```
from rest_framework import routers

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('articles', views.ArticleView)
router.register('tags', views.TagView)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
]
```

Comment: Your models are fine, but you might need to do some work on your views.  Why not post your views.py?

Comment: Good idea @RedCricket. I've added my views. If they were regular CBVs I'd have a fair idea about how to do it, but I'm kinda new to DRF.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Overriding the **`create()`** method of the serializer as

```
class ArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tags = serializers.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        tag = validated_data.pop('tags')
        tag_instance, created = Tag.objects.get_or_create(name=tag)
        article_instance = Article.objects.create(**validated_data, tags=tag_instance)
        return article_instance
```

Comment: Thanks! Your answer has gotten me a lot closer! However, I was hoping to create multiple tag objects (each with a single word as the name). To extend your answer to do this, I think I need to move the `ForeignKey` from `Article` to `Tag` and change some other stuff around. Since I think their might have been some confusion about what the expected behaviour was meant to be, I'll mark your solution as correct, and then post mine as well when I get it working.

Comment: I think, **`M2M`** relation would be better for `Tags`

Comment: Your Article relation to tag need to be a ManyToManyField so you could add multiple tag objects.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, thanks to @JPG for their help. This is what I've ended up with. It allows users to add space delimited tags into a `CharField` on the `/api/blog/article` endpoint. When a POST request is performed, the tags are split on spaces, `get_or_create()`d (for this to work I needed to make `Tag.name` the primary key), and then added to the `Article` with `article.tags.set(tag_list)`. As @JPG and @Martins suggested, a `ManyToManyField()` was the best way to do this.

Here is my full code:

*serializers.py:*

```
class ArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class TagsField(serializers.CharField):

        def to_representation(self, tags):
            tags = tags.all()
            return "".join([(tag.name + " ") for tag in tags]).rstrip(' ')


    tags = TagsField()

    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):

        tags = validated_data.pop('tags') # Removes the 'tags' entry
        tag_list = []
        for tag in tags.split(' '):
            tag_instance, created = Tag.objects.get_or_create(name=tag)
            tag_list += [tag_instance]

        article = Article.objects.create(**validated_data)
        print(tag_list)
        article.tags.set(tag_list)
        article.save()
        return article


class TagSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Tag
        fields = '__all__'
```

Note that I had to create a custom `TagField()` and override `to_representation()`. This is because if I used a regular `serializer.CharField()` tags were displayed as: "Blog.tag.None" instead of the tag values, like this:

[image: Blog.tag.None]

*models.py:*

```
class Tag(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=32, primary_key=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)

class Article(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('date', 'id')
```